# How to create a line chart in R with x axis labels that are dates from table data?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I have a large data set which contains observations made on different dates. I would like to visualize in R the frequency of observations based on the month in which they were made. I used table to count the number of rows per date:

```
freq_by_month <- c(table(format(dataframe_name$Date_Collected,"%Y-%m")))
```

Now I would like to create a line chart showing these data points over time, and label the points with the date of collection.

I've tried using

```
plot(freq_by_month, type="o", xlab="Date", ylab="a y label goes here")
```

Which gives me a graph with numeric x axis labels.

[image: Graph with numeric data labels.]

I've also tried

```
plot(freq_by_month, type="o", xaxt="n", xlab="Date", ylab="a y label goes here")
axis(1, at=1:34, labels=TRUE)
```

Which just produces a graph with numbers at smaller intervals. I think I need to set the labels as a vector or something, but I'm not sure how to do that from the table. I do not want to do this by hand, because I will be adding new data points every month.

For reference,

```
str(freq_by_month)
 Named int [1:34] 1 1 9 1 3 4 2 1 1 3 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:34] "2012-03" "2015-06" "2015-07" "2015-08"
 head(freq_by_month)
2012-03 2015-06 2015-07 2015-08 2016-01 2016-02 
      1       1       9       1       3       4
```

If I'm going about this totally backward, and I shouldn't use a table to count the data in the first place, I would be glad to know that too.

Comment: The 1st link shows how to create a vector of sequential dates, which is not relevant in this case. Knowing how to create a vector from a row in a table could be a solution, though. The 2nd link has similar problems with seqential/random data, and is therefore not applicable. The 3rd link is for a barplot, which produces a plot with correct labels and doesn't have the same problem. It also suggests creating a vector by hand (which would be tedious for a large data set, and would change every month), and is for sequential dates, which is also irrelevant. Last link has similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving this.

```
df<-read.xlsx("data set file.xlsx",1, header=TRUE, fill=TRUE) 
 #Import the data ("name of file", sheet number, etc.)

str(df)
'data.frame':   911 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Date: Date, format: "2012-03-23" "2015-06-15" ...
 $ Col2: chr  "lorem" "ipsum" ...
 $ Col3: chr  "lorem" "ipsum" .... #etc.

df$Month <-as.Date(cut(df$date, breaks="month") 
 #adds a column ("Month") with the Date rounded down 
 #to the first of each month 

df2 <-df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(date_column_name=n()) #summarizes the number of 
                                  #observations by month

str(df2)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   34 obs. of  2 
variables:
$ Month    : Date, format: "2012-03-01" "2015-06-01" ...
$ Summarized_Column: int  1 1 9 1 3 4 2 1 1 3 ...

df3 = as.data.frame(df2) #Converts df2 to a data frame.

#all the prettiness for plotting:
ggplot(df3, aes(x=Month, y=Date, color=(Month))) + 
  geom_point()+
  labs(title="Title", x="", y="Y Axis Title") +
  ylim(c(0,1000))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 months", date_labels= "%b-%y") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust=1, hjust = 1), #rotates labels and shift location
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="gray97", colour="black"),
    axis.text=element_text(size=11),
    axis.title = element_text(size=13),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuX3I.png)